# To find the area of a given curve.

Tags: area, curves

The curve is given $$x =(1-t^{3})/(1+t^{2})$$ and $$y= 2t/(1+t^{2})$$

I know the method for finding the area, but I'm having problem with the tracing of curves. In exams, I won't really have time to trace the curve by finding values of $x$ and $y$ using values of $t$.

I just want to have a rough idea about the curve, so that I can find the values of $t$ for which the curve makes a complete loop.

How to do it?

Comment: A curve has no area.

Comment: How would I know this$?$ I mean how can we know if the curve has area or not$?$

Comment: Is it definitely meant to be $t^3$ in $x$? Because if it were $t^2$ instead, we'd have the parameterization $x=\cos 2\theta,\,y=\sin 2\theta,\,t=\tan\theta$.

Comment: Curves in general have length, they do not have area. Surfaces have area.

Comment: Did you mean area *under* the curve?

Comment: @J.G. yes I meant the area enclosed by the curve

Comment: @J.G. this is what I was thinking, there should be $t^{2}$. But if the question is right, then how would I know the enclosed area $?$

Comment: I think you need some other lines bounding the area, e.g. maybe we want $\int_0^aydx$ with $x=a\implies y=0$. In this case, we'd take $a=1$. Then you just need $\int_0^1y\dot{x}dt$ (note that $t=0\implies x=1,\,t=1\implies x=0$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The  curve $y(x)$ does not form a loop itself. It is the area enclosed by $y(x)$, the y-axis and the x-axis. Then, it is easy to verify that the curve intersects the x-axis at (1,0) and y-axis at (0,1). As a result, the area

$$I = \int_0^1 y(x)dx$$

can be carried out with the variable substitutions $x=(1-t^3)/(1+t^2)$ and $y=2t/(1+t^2)$. Explicitly,

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\left[1-\frac{1}{1+t^2}+\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^2}\right]dt$$

which can then be integrated piecewise.

[image]

Comment: Also, the curve should be bounded by $y$ axis. At $t=0$ the point is $(1,0)$ and at $t=1$ the point is $(0,1)$. If the curve is bounded by both axes, then this solution is alright.

Comment: Correct, the variable $t$ is bound by [0,1].